# Windows 10 Log-in Takes Forever

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, nod32

I had an issue with ProfSvc. I knew it was caused by eset nod32 antivirus blocking the Profile Service. I tried to uninstall nod32 in Safe Mode, but it didn't work in safe mode. I downloaded eset uninstaller (offered by eset)  and run it in safe mode. It uninstalled the antivirus for me successfully.
When I tried to log in, I got no more ProfSvc error, but the login process takes forever and doesn't proceed to showing the desktop.

I don't really want to reinstall the windows. Are there any suggestions to fix this problem?
Oh, by the way, it doesn't log in even in Safe Mode anymore.
The only way to get through is command prompt now.

Comment: Are you able to show the desktop when you open up the task manager? What do you see? Does it stuck in "loading"? Or what does the display show?

Comment: No, I van, it doesn't go further than the login page. I just type the password and hit enter  a small circle will show it's loading. No access to task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system is seriously loused up, probably by the uninstallation of nod32.

I can see only two methods, and both will require booting from the
[Windows 10 installation media](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html)
and choosing "Troubleshoot":

[**System Restore**](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html)

This might be able to restore your computer to before you uninstalled nod32,
but then you will still have the Profile Service problem, which you will
need to solve in another way than the one that destroyed your Windows.

It might be possible that this won't restore all the nod32 files deleted by the
uninstallation, so in effect nod32 will be only partially installed and perhaps non-functional, so in this way solving the Profile Service problem,
although in a left-handed manner.

[**Refresh Windows**](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4090-refresh-windows-10-a.html)

This will reinstall Windows from the manufacturer image, erasing all the
applications you installed since receiving the computer.
With some luck, you might be able to choose to keep your own files,
but basically you would be restarting from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Harry. Actually I ended up reinstalling the windows because none of Microsoft methods worked for me. And I couldn't actually do a system restore as it was turned off. Thanks for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest leaving system restore enabled, since it can be a life saver in such situations.